# Problem: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused

Tags: java, curl

I have a problem to send requests to the backend of my project, I already tried deactivating the firewall and proxy but did not get results.
As far as I can see, there is a port through which my request passes first and it doesn't let me get to the backend.

I already tested with cURL by console and Postman but there was no result. By console I get this error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused

The project is made in Java with Spring and I use webservices.

Here is an example of my request:

```
curl http://localhost:9081/auth/login/
```

And this is the result request

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused

What can i do?

Comment: Is the service listening on port 1080? Your example is using port 9081, not 1080 as in the error message. Is the service actually on `localhost` or is it somewhere else?

Comment: It's true...the port on the request and the port mentioned in the error message don't match. And what does this have to do with javaScript, php or rabbitmq exactly? Don't tag things at random, or if they don't relate directly to the question.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear why curl would try to connect to a different port than the one explicitly specified...are you using some sort of tunnelling or port forwarding? We have no idea of your network topology. I doubt there is enough information here for anyone to do much more than speculate about the possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my application.properties has:
`server.port = 9081
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Yes, I use port 9081, but for some reason redirects me to port 1080 and does not let me pass the request there. I found out that this port is assigned to SOCKS proxy but I don't know how to disable them.

Comment: If you already have a proxy listening to 9081, then change your application.properties to use a different port, and direct your requests to the port without conflicts.

Comment: I have this same issue. I'm running curl in WSL2. No matter what port I put in the URL, it always tries to connect to port 1080, which I verified with tcpdump. I used the --no-proxy option, so it is not trying to use a proxy.

Comment: My problem was the I used "--no-proxy" while the correct syntax is "--noproxy". When setting "--no-proxy" it does not complain about the option error, but redirects to 1080 for some reason I don't undertand. I have http_proxy and https_proxy unset. I'm acutally trying to connect to host.example.com, but have "127.0.0.1 host.example.com" in /etc/hosts. Without --no-proxy (wrong syntax) and --noproxy it connects to localhost, but with the wrong syntax it connects to port 1080.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have env variable HTTP_PROXY set. In My case, after removing the the environment variable.. 'curl' command executed successfully.

Comment: With curl you can also use the option --noproxy "*". In the OP cas: curl http://localhost:9081/auth/login/ --noproxy "*". Though, in the OP case, calls to localhost are normally not proxied, for example by setting the environment variable  NO_PROXY=localhost, 127.0.0.1 (how you actually do that depends on the OS)

Answer (score 0):

check your path Environment Variables on your windows (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System->Advanced system settings and select environment variables). look at User variables. if you find the variable http_proxy please delete it quickly and Done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see any difference between your answer and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333395/problem-curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-1080-connection-refused/58080371#58080371). What am I missing?